NET Maui - How do I populate a Picker manually in C# with a list of objects Without using MVC
I have a working Picker if I manually set the items in a loop using strings.
And I am getting the OnChange and getting the string value with  picker.Items[picker.SelectedIndex]
I have these objects.
<Picker x:Name="Event"
  Title="Select an Event"
  SelectedIndexChanged="OnEventIndexChanged">
</Picker>

public class Location
{
  public string LocationID { get; set; }
  public string LocationName { get; set; }
}

I have this working.
List<Location> L3 = DB.Table<Location>().ToList();
foreach (var L in L3)
  Event.Items.Add(L.LocationName);

What I need to do is have the picker use the List of Location objects to:

Have the picker show Location.LocationNames
OnSelect be able to retrieve the LocationID for the corrisponding SelectedName.

The docs for Picker say you can set it to an IList but I don't know how to convert from
List
To
IList
I am not using  MVC.
Please do not give examples that use MVC in any way.

If you are not using MVC what are you using ?

"but I don't know how to convert from List To IList". A List is an IList there is nothing to convert.

I suppose I am using MVC since my app has a XAML "View" file. But I am not using any model/view functionality to populate or handle the controls. I am doing everythign in C#. This complicated app is working fine I just need to know how to use => straight C# to populate a Picker from a list of objects and return an element from the object =>that isn't the element displayed  in the Picker. Just like  a html select you have the DISPLAY items and the DATA items IN THE html select itself. Also " A List is an IList there is nothing to convert.' Got it, since this does work! Event.ItemsSource = L3;

do this
Event.ItemsSource = L3;
Event.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("LocationName");

to get the selected ID in SelectedIndexChanged
var event = (Event)Event.ItemsSource[Event.SelectedIndex];
var id = event.EventNumber;


This works! But I a need to get LocationID from the picker not LocationName and the L3 list of objects it gone after I populate the picker thus I can't use the SelectedIndex to get the LocationID from L3 in the OnChange. Is there a call to tell the picker what items to return from the object? Something like Event.ItemDATABinding = new Binding("LocationID"); ? Really all I am trying to do is use a picker like a html select....

Sure you can.  Just maintain a reference to L3 and use L3[Event.SelectedIndex].LocationID;. Or you can use Event.ItemsSource instead of L3 but you will have to cast it to the correct type first

I can't use L3 in the OnChange(). This is a list of objects that lives only to populate the Picker and then is disposed. Can you give an example of how I would use Event.ItemSource to get the LocationID? I have no idea how to use it or cast it to Location.LocationID..... tx

again, there is no reason you can't keep a reference to L3 .  But see my last edit

After spending some time in the debugger looking at what is availble from the picker in it's OnChange(), I finally figured this out with Your help!
THANK YOU!
void OnEventIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Location SelectedLocation = (Location) picker.ItemsSource[picker.SelectedIndex];
Log.Text += SelectedLocation.LocationID;
}

You can achieve above using a solution as outlined here.
Refer to the code shown below for reference:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

public class Location // Class to hold location data
{
    public string LocationID { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadLocations();
        PopulatePicker();
    }

    private void LoadLocations()
    {
        Locations = new List<Location> // Sample data
        {
            new Location { LocationID = "1", LocationName = "Location A" },
            new Location { LocationID = "2", LocationName = "Location B" },
            new Location { LocationID = "3", LocationName = "Location C" }
        };
    }

    private void PopulatePicker()
    {
        foreach (var location in Locations)
        {
            EventPicker.Items.Add(location.LocationName);
        }
    }

    private void OnEventIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = (Picker)sender;
        int selectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;

        if (selectedIndex != -1)
        {
            var selectedLocation = Locations[selectedIndex];
            string locationID = selectedLocation.LocationID;
            DisplayAlert("Selected Location", $"ID: {locationID}, Name: {selectedLocation.LocationName}", "OK");
        }
    }
}

In the template use above as below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YourNamespace.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Picker x:Name="EventPicker"
                Title="Select an Event"
                SelectedIndexChanged="OnEventIndexChanged"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>


Typo alert - it's achieve - not "archieve" (no "r" in that word)

Ahh yes thanks for the edit @marc_s.. :-)

One of the requirements was to get LocationID -from the picker data- not from the List of Locations which is a local var and is disposed after setting up the picker, but tx for the effort to help...
